# Why am I getting an "expected constant expression" error for the array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, constant-expression

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    float maximum = -1000000;

    std::ifstream points;

    int size = 100;
    float x[size][2]; // <<< error
    while (count < size) {
        points >> x[count][0];
        points >> x[count][1];

        count++;
    }
}
```

This program is giving me expected constant expression error on the line where I declare `float x[size][2]`. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
float x[size][2];
```

That doesn't work because declared arrays can't have runtime sizes. Try a vector:

```
std::vector< std::array<float, 2> > x(size);
```

Or use new

```
// identity<float[2]>::type *px = new float[size][2];
float (*px)[2] = new float[size][2];

// ... use and then delete
delete[] px;
```

---

If you don't have C++11 available, you can use `boost::array` instead of `std::array`.

If you don't have boost available, make your own array type you can stick into vector

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct array {
  T data[N];
  T &operator[](ptrdiff_t i) { return data[i]; }
  T const &operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const { return data[i]; }
};
```

For easing the syntax of `new`, you can use an `identity` template which effectively is an in-place typedef (also available in `boost`)

```
template<typename T> 
struct identity {
  typedef T type;
};
```

---

If you want, you can also use a vector of `std::pair<float, float>`

```
std::vector< std::pair<float, float> > x(size);
// syntax: x[i].first, x[i].second
```

Answer (score 8):

The array will be allocated at compile time, and since `size` is not a constant, the compiler cannot accurately determine its value.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have variable length arrays (as they are called in C99) in C++. You need to use dynamically allocated arrays (if the size varies) or a static integral constant expression for size.

Answer (score 2):

The line `float x[size][2]` won't work, because arrays have to be allocated at compile time (with a few compiler-specific exceptions). If you want to be able to easily change the size of the array `x` at *compile* time, you can do this:

```
 #define SIZE 100
 float x[SIZE][2];
```

If you really want to allocate the array based on information you only have at runtime, you need to allocate the array dynamically with `malloc` or `new`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of an automatic array must be a compile-time constant.

```
 const int size = 100;
 float x[size][2];
```

If the size weren't known at compile-time (e.g entered by the user, determined from the contents of the file), you'd need to use dynamic allocation, for example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<float, float> > x(somesize);
```

(Instead of a pair, a dedicated Point struct/class would make perfect sense.)

Answer (score 2):

Because it expected a constant expression!

Array dimensions in C (ignoring C99's VLAs) and C++ must be quantities known at compile-time. That doesn't mean just labelled with `const`: they *have* to be hard-coded into the program.

Use dynamic allocation or `std::vector` (which is a wrapper around dynamic array allocation) to determine array sizes at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

It is a restriction of the language.  Array sizes must be constant expressions.  Here's a partial jsutification from cplusplus.com

> NOTE: The elements field within brackets [] which represents the number of elements the array is going to hold, must be a constant value, since arrays are blocks of non-dynamic memory whose size must be determined before execution. In order to create arrays with a variable length dynamic memory is needed, which is explained later in these tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned any value to size; thus the compiler cannot allocate the memory for the array. (An array of null size? What?)

Additionally, you'd need to make SIZE a constant, and not a variable.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, this response no longer makes sense since the poster has changed their question.