# Creating array with constant

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constant-expression

I was working on a program in Netbeans on Linux using a gcc compiler when, upon switching to Visual C++ on Windows 7, the code failed to compile as Visual C++ says it `expected constant expression` on several lines. On Netbeans, I simply did something similar to `char name[fullName.size()];`, while on Visual C++, I tried, among other things,

```
const int position = fullName.size();
char Name[position];
```

How can I create a constant to use for the array?

Note: I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448380/c-expected-constant-expression), but is there any way I can get this working without using vectors, since that would require a re-write of many parts of the program?

Comment: The actual question here is "How can I create an array of a non-predetermined size on the stack?" And the answer is, you can't in VC++.

Comment: what is fullname.size() ? looks like a function call, that would be runtime call and thus not a constant expression.

Comment: fullname.size() is the length of the string. It's a function call

Comment: Could you give this more context? I don't see how using vector here would effect other parts of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VC++ you can't do runtime declarations of stack array sizes, but you can do stack allocation via [_alloca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5(VS.80).aspx)

so this:

```
const int position = fullName.size();
char Name[position];
```

becomes this:

```
const int position = fullName.size();
char * Name = (char*)_alloca(position * sizeof(char));
```

It's not quite the same thing, but it's as close as you are going to get in VC++.

Comment: I think we should steer the asker toward the heap... I don't want to see a beginner start writing code with _alloca

Comment: @George: The heap might be a better choice for an array of objects, but for a simple string buffer, it's a worse choice.

Comment: Why not just use std::string? He says he's a beginner, that's the easiest thing to use.

Comment: Never mind guys, I found out a way to skip using arrays/vectors entirely. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @George: Because he asked how to solve a specific problem, not how to redesign his code using a completely different API.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in VC++. I know, pretty sad :(

The solutions include:

- Create it on the heap
- Make it constant

The new C++ standard (C++0x) proposes a 'constant expression' feature to deal with this. For more info, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) out.

Comment: Thanks! I can't make it constant since I have no idea what the size of the string will be. What do you mean by "creating it on the heap?" Sorry, I'm still a novice at programming.

Comment: Allocate memory using `new` and free with `delete`

Comment: Which really means use `vector`. There is *no* reason to have raw memory allocations hanging about, they leak and make your life more difficult.

Comment: I'm not saying use `new` and `delete` directly - I'm just explaining what the heap is.

Answer (score 1):

C++ requires that the size of the array be known at compile time. If you don't mind using a non-standard extension, gcc does allow code like you're doing (note that while it's not standard C++, it *is* standard in C, as of C99).

I'd also guess that you could use a vector (in this particular place) with less trouble than you believe though -- quite a bit of code that's written for an array can work with a vector with only a re-compile, and little or no rewriting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `char name[fullName.size()];` is an example of a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which - as far as I know - are not standardized in C++ so you're at the mercy of the compiler.
[Slightly off-topic they're part of the C99 standard]