# Why am I able to create an array of size only known at runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays

In my university script it's written that we're not allowed to create a local array at runtime with size only known at runtime.

> float x[size][2];
>   That doesn't work because declared arrays can't have runtime sizes. Try a vector:

From: [C++ expected constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448380/c-expected-constant-expression)

However this code compiles under Apple LLVM 8.0.0

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
     int i = 5;

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    int array[x];

    for(int i = 0; i<x; ++i){
        std::cout << array[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

Edit: And works fine. Prints out garbage as expected.

Reminder: This program is not meant to make any sense.

Comment: It's a non-standard compiler extension. If you compile with `-pedantic-errors` it should refuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called "variable length arrays", and is a compiler extension; it is not part of the standard.

If you compile with `-pedantic`, Clang gives you this warning:

```
main.cpp:9:14: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
    int array[x];
```

Don't use this feature if you need your code to be portable.

Comment: It's a *compiler extension*, or a *part of the C99 standard*? I don't have the standard at hand, and the Clang warning sort of contradicts the answer body.

Comment: @Kroltan Both. It's a compiler extension for C++ code and valid in C99.